# How to make everything bigger on the page?

Tags: html, css, size

If I open my web site in a browser and pres `Ctrl +` several time everything gets bigged and the site looks better to me.

Can I achieve the same effect by putting something in the HTML code (so that the users see everything bigger by default, without pressing `Ctrl+`)?

I want to make everything bigger (text and images).

Comment: its called zoom by the way

Comment: Zoom the entire page

Comment: OK, how to zoom the entire page by editing its HTML?

Comment: I am not sure and i din't tried too. Isn't chaning the width and height for all the elemetns

Answer (score 8):

If you want to achieve the same effect that the browser zoom, you can use the CSS `zoom` property *(and the `transform scale(x)` property for Firefox)* on the `body` :

```
body {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3); /* for Firefox, default 1*/
    zoom:130%; /* For Chrome, IE, default 100%*/
}
```

But, I'm not sure if this is a good solution. If you think your website looks better when zoomed in, then there is a real design issue somewhere. I would suggest you to rework the design first.