# Trigger media queries when content gets bigger

Tags: javascript, css, browser

If I open my website in a browser and press **Ctrl +** everything gets bigger. Also, my media queries get triggered, when the content gets to big for the screen. Just like they would when the screen gets to small for content.

Now I want to implement exactly this feature with buttons in my webpage. I tried to change the font-size of the body and also tried it on the html-tag. But nothing works. My media queries won't get triggered when the content gets to big.

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using media queries in EM by the way (like `@media all and (min-width:75em) {/*my declarations*/}` )

[Using css-zoom or -transform like someone proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605730/how-to-make-everything-bigger-on-the-page) didn't work for this issue.

*Edit*: 
Here are some visual examples to clarify my question:

This is the smashing magazine website at 1920px width:
[image]

Here is what I get, when I user **Strg +** to zoom the content to 200%:
[image]
As you can see, everything is still "in place", the site still looks fine.

But when I use in the css eg.: `html { font-size:2em }`, the output is as follows:
[image]
Everything is out of place.

I search a way to use browser zoom via css or js.

Comment: Can you give us and example please?

Comment: You cannot trigger media queries.